# fancybox, make slideshow with images and divs that are not the gallery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, fancybox, slideshow, fancybox-2

I am using the jQuery [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin to create an image gallery. User clicks on an image and then a modal shows up to navigate through all the images. Up to this point, everything is done with the following code .

But **the change I want to do** is in the modal slide show. The slideshow needs to show  the particular image that was clicked on plus other images which are not in the gallery plus extra `div`s. Those extra images and `divs` may stay anywhere in the code.

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="img/a_small.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Project">
<img src="img/a_big.jpg"    alt="image project"/>
</a>

<a class="fancybox" href="img/b_small.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Project">
<img src="img/b_big.jpg"    alt="image project"/>
</a>

<a class="fancybox" href="img/c_small.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Project">
<img src="img/c_big.jpg"    alt="image project"/>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 150, 
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150,
    closeClick : true,
    'autoSize': false,
    'autoWidth'    : 600,
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'type'          : 'swf',
    'autoCenter ' :true,
    'aspectRatio':true
});
```

1) How to achieve that ?

2) If fancybox is not a good fit, is there any other script that will help to achieve the purpose in a responsive design way ?

**EDIT:**
An online demo is [here](http://demo2.lumierebd.com/).

Comment: I think that you can use some plugin event, like `beforeLoad()` or `beforeShow()`. The idea is add images or whatever you need to fancybox from there.

Comment: @kmsdev, How can I exclude all the images except the triggering one and  add other images ? any clue in the doc etc?

Comment: It's just an idea, but you could clone your original container, delete items from the  original and add some new ones. When modal closes, just replace the original modified by the cloned one.

Comment: @kmsdev, `EDIT:` added.Firebug shows `<Object />` element is out there. I do not know how to handle it. Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking and I see that if you add `data-fancybox-group` to other elements that you want to add to the gallery, fancybox gets them and works as expected.

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vmodxmk/) as example (images don't load in jsFiddle but if you copy the code to a file you can se how it works).

PS. You have some incorrect attributes in your images. Look for `width11=""` and `height11=""`.

Comment: what is about adding new `div`s that may contain button etc ? And obviously I want the other images ( images that are not in gallery)  and `div`s to be hidden in the page

Comment: About images that are not in gallery, you have only to use `.fancybox` class with the `data-attribute`. Currently, I don't know if it works with divs, I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry dude, as I saw, it won't work for divs mixed with images grouped by same name. You can see what I tried so far [here](http://i3rt2.kmsdev.net).

Comment: did you use any images that are not in the gallery but will show in the slideshow ? I did not find any such image in your demo.

Comment: Yes, the last image (the latest image in the code) is in another div, but adding the `data-fancybox-group` and setting it to the same name as the gallery, the image will be shown too.

Comment: but the `div` and other images (which are not in the gallery) should be kept hidden before showing them in the show. How to do that ?

Comment: Then you will need to use the `beforeShow` event to show these hidden images. The use is something like `beforeShow: function(){ console.log( $('img', this.element) ); }`.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in anchor tag

```
    rel="group1"
    rel="group1"
    rel="group2"
    rel="group2"
```

or

```
     data-fancybox="group_1"
    data-fancybox="group_1"
    data-fancybox="group_2"
    data-fancybox="group_2"

<a data-fancybox="group_<?= $counter ?>" class="fancybox" href="image_path"></a>
```

Comment: in this way you can create multiple groups gallery on same page.